# Is the iTunes album artist property broken for AppleScript queries?

Tags: applescript, itunes

The following script does not work as I expect:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    tell source "Library"
        tell playlist "Music"
            set theTracks to (every track whose album artist is "xxx" and album is "Fiddle Tunes 2006 Concert")
            count of theTracks
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

It matches tracks whose album artist property is empty. It should match no tracks. That particular album title has no tracks with a non-empty album artist field (and no tracks with the compilation flag set).

It I replace album artist with artist, it matches no tracks, which is correct.

Am I missing something obvious or is this a bug in iTunes?

Comment: It doesn't match any empty album artists in my library, of course I don't have any empty fields so I had to empty one.. but it didn't match it afterwards. So maybe its your setup?

Comment: It seems that the problem does not depend on the album artist field being empty. I have tried the same query with several different album titles and they all act as if the album artist part of the query was not there. Next I tried swapping the order of the fields in the query, and it worked properly!

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, fixed in macOS 10.12.5 and iTunes 12.6.1.25.